# How do I change the color of a pop-up on the main page?

Tags: php

everyone! I know that here I will be helped to solve my request

Who knows where I can find out how to change the color of pop-ups n my site ?
https://ferberg.de/
Is it possible to change the shape of pop-ups?
I want to make the site more flexible and user-friendly

Comment: You'll need to find out whether your pop-ups are coming from your theme, or a plugin. You could try standard debugging - change themes and see if they change; disable plugins one by one to find which one it is. From there, you can contact the theme or plugin author for support. You may also be able to use Additional CSS in the Customizer to style them yourself, if that option is available on your site.